# AngularJS Reload controller variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i would reload variable in controller that use for navbar.

I have controller for each view. I use a controller, loginCtrl, to login after i logged i would reload the var set in "rootController".

I use a variable for ng-if to switch button login and logout in navbar, but this variable (in rootController) is getting to call a factory function.

The problem are that variable one time is set don't change when i change value of factory. The solution is reload only rootController to reset var, search to internet i found $route.reload().
I've create a function in rootController and i use it so:

```
 $rootScope.reload = function(){ $timeout(function () {
                                           $route.reload();
                                           }, 0);
                                };
```

but when i call in other controller the app loads infinity.

How resolve it?

EDIT:

```
angular.module('appModule',[])
.controller('AppCtrl',function ($scope,$rootScope,UserLogged){
       $scope.isLogged = UserLogged.isLogged();
       $scope.user = UserLogged.get();
 });
.config(...) // To configure route, one route have loginCtrl as controller

.controller('loginCtrl',function($scope,$http,UserLogged){
    $http.get(..).sucess(function(data){UserLogged.set(data)}) 
                         // call a WS to setup the factory UserLogged    
)

.factory('UserLogged',function(){
var userLogged
var isLogged
 // set and get method
}
```

All work fine but when i update the isLogged var in factory the app don't update $scope.isLogged in AppCtrl. The solution are reload AppCtrl to recall UserLogged.get() and reset $scope.isLogged with the new value.

SOLVED:

@ rtvalluri Thanks

```
// App control
$scope.$on('loginLogout',function(){
     $scope.isLogged = UserLogged.isLogged();
     $scope.userLogged = UserLogged.get();
});

// loginCtrl
$http.get(..).sucess(function(data){
                                    UserLogged.set(data);
                                    $scope.$emit('loginLogout');
                                   })
```

Comment: Can you post the code form loginCtrl use to set the variable in the factory, post he complete factory code and post how the rootCtrl uses the variable from factory?

Comment: So emitting the event solved your issue finally ;) Cheers .. :) @Fabrizio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try emitting two events for login and logout, with which you can update variable in rootController without refreshing it

In your navbar

```
<button ng-if="!isLoggedIn">Login</button>
<button ng-if="isLoggedIn">Logout</button>
```

If mainController is the rootController and login and logout are the two different functions in two different controllers,

then keep listening in rootController using:

```
$scope.$on('login',function(event,data){
  //assume 'isLoggedIn' is the boolean value
  $scope.isLoggedIn = data;
});

$scope.$on('logout',function(event,data){
  $scope.isLoggedIn = data;
});
```

Try emitting 'login' event from Login Controller

```
//on successful login, trigger below event
$scope.$emit('login',true);
```

and in Logout Controller

```
//on successful logout, trigger below event
$scope.$emit('logout',false);
```

Note: Above approach works only if mainController is the parent controller for other controllers, otherwise try emitting events on $rootScope instead of $scope